# What is the difference - 'I am asked' vs 'I get asked'?

Tags: passive-voice

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> I get asked that question a lot.
>
> I am asked that question a lot.

Comment: What's the context in which you found these sentences or want to use them?

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference is primarily one of register.  **get asked** is conversational whereas **am asked** is neutral.

to be asked

to get asked

**get**  + past participle **asked**  emphasizes the transitive nature of **ask**. Perhaps that makes it a tad "rougher".

Comment: a spoken form versus a standard written form for the passive is how I would phrase it.

Comment: @Lambie: **am asked** is not exclusively "a written form" so I'd have to disagree.   *I'm asked that question quite often* is something you'd *hear* not just read.